# Can someone please explain the meaning of the following awk script?

Tags: awk

The following awk script was written for me to remove records with empty fields in my inputfile. But I have difficulty to understand it. Would you please explain it in details why it is written like that.

`awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==""){next}}1' inputfile`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's break it up into components:

```
awk                    # The actual program
-F,                    # Set the field delimiter to a comma
'{                     # Beginning of the main series of action statements
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)     # Your typical for loop.   NF is the number of fields 
                       # in the input
  if($i==""){          # $i will expand to e. g. $1, then $2, etc.,  which 
                       # is each field in the input data
                       # If it is "" (or an empty string):
     next}             # Skip to the next entry.  End of conditional
                       # and of the foor loop (no braces here)
}                      # End of the main series of action statements
1'                     # awkish shorthand basically for `print`, and end of
                       # the script
inputfile              # The file to be processed
```

Since `awk`'s default action is to include data, the script simply skips records with any empty data fields, and prints everything not skipped.

Comment: Nice explanation but you got the closing braces wrong.